# How can I get Kafka Consumer to process LocalDate type?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, jackson

I changed one of my fields from a `string` to a `LocalDate` type, and now my Kafka Consumer cannot process it. After reading the below error, it looks like I need to deserialize this value. I thought amending the `consumerFactory` below to include a `LocalDateDeserializer` would resolve this but it hasn't. Do I need to create a custom deserializer or can I amend some of the configuration in my `consumerFactory`?

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Can't deserialize data [[...125]] from topic [Service.Topic]
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `java.time.LocalDate` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
```

Code:

```
public ConsumerFactory<String, Request> consumerFactory() {
Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();
config.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
config.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
config.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, LocalDateDeserializer.class);
config.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
```

Answer (score 2):

This resolved the issue! I used the below annotations on my declaration of the field.

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateDeserializer.class)
@JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateSerializer.class)
```

Comment: Worth to note that those classes are available in `jackson-datatype-jsr310` dependency mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not problem with Kafka but with Jackson.

Kafka uses Jackson by default to serialize/deserialize. You can register `JavaTimeModule` for the `ObjectMapper` and build `JsonDeserializer` with it. Then build your custom `ConsumerFactory` :

```
public ConsumerFactory<String, Request> consumerFactory() {

     ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
     objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());

     Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();
     config.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);

     StringDeserializer keyDeserializer = new StringDeserializer();
     JsonDeserializer<Request> jsonDeserializer = new JsonDeserializer<>(objectMapper);

     ConsumerFactory<String, Request> factory = new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(config, keyDeserializer,  jsonDeserializer);
     return factory;
}
```

You will have to add [jackson-datatype-jsr310](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-jsr310) dependency to your project to make `JavaTimeModule` accessible.

And if you are using spring-boot and would like to configure `ObjectMapper` globally you could do the following for example :

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaConfig {
    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, Request> consumerFactory(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder objectMapperBuilder) {

        Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);

        StringDeserializer keyDeserializer = new StringDeserializer();
        JsonDeserializer<Request> jsonDeserializer = new JsonDeserializer<>(objectMapperBuilder.build());

        ConsumerFactory<String, Request> factory = new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(config, keyDeserializer,  jsonDeserializer);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder objectMapperBuilder() {
        Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
        builder.modulesToInstall(new JavaTimeModule());
        return builder;
    }
}
```